# How to create 3D array of optionals w/ set size

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array, option-type, uint16

How would I go about creating a 3-dimensional array of `UInt16?` with a set size where each element is by default set to `nil`?

My attempt was

```
var courseInfo = UInt16?(count:10, repeatedValue: UInt16?(count:10, repeatedValue: UInt16?(count:10, repeatedValue:nil)))
```

although that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: if the answer helped you, please mark it as the "accepted answer", it helps more people :)

Comment: I will don't worry (: I'm just still figuring out some kinks with my code related to it

Comment: Great. Let us know if there's any other questions you need answered!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code errored because you weren't creating arrays, you were mixing them up with UInt16?s.

Let's start at the base case, how do you make a one-dimensional array?

```
Array<UInt16?>(count: 10, repeatedValue: nil)
```

What if we wanted a two dimensional array? Well, now we are no longer initializing an `Array<UInt16?>` we are initializing an Array of Arrays of UInt16?, where each sub-array is initialized with UInt16?s.

```
Array<Array<UInt16?>>(count:10, repeatedValue: Array<UInt16?>(count:10, repeatedValue:nil))
```

Repeating this for the 3-dimensional case just requires more of the same ugly nesting:

```
var courseInfo = Array<Array<Array<UInt16?>>>(count:10, repeatedValue: Array<Array<UInt16?>>(count:10, repeatedValue: Array<UInt16?>(count:10, repeatedValue:nil)))
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, or to model a 3D structure, but this is the closest thing to your code right now.

EDIT:

Martin in the comments pointed out that a neater solution is

```
var courseInfo : [[[UInt16?]]] = Array(count: 10, repeatedValue: Array(count : 10, repeatedValue: Array(count: 10, repeatedValue: nil)))
```

Which works by moving the type declaration out front, making the `repeatedValue:` parameter unambiguous.

Comment: Alternatively: `let courseInfo : [[[UInt16?]]] =  Array(count: 10, repeatedValue: Array(count : 10, repeatedValue: Array(count: 10, repeatedValue: nil)))`

Comment: Much neater, by putting the type declaration out front and letting the parser figure out the rest. +1, I'd add this to the answer but I don't know how to credit you in it :/

Comment: Don't worry about that :)

Answer (score 1):

Build yourself an abstraction to allow:

```
var my3DArrayOfOptionalUInt16 = Matrix<UInt16?> (initial: nil, dimensions: 10, 10, 10)
```

using something like:

```
struct Matrix<Item> {

  var items : [Item]
  var dimensions : [Int]

  var rank : Int {
    return dimensions.count
  }

  init (initial: Item, dimensions : Int...) {
    precondition(Matrix.allPositive(dimensions))
    self.dimensions = dimensions
    self.items = [Item](count: dimensions.reduce(1, combine: *), repeatedValue: initial)
  }

  subscript (indices: Int...) -> Item {
    precondition (Matrix.validIndices(indices, dimensions))
    return items[indexFor(indices)]
  }

  func indexFor (indices: [Int]) -> Int {
    // Compute index into `items` based on `indices` x `dimensions`
    // ... row-major-ish
    return 0
  }

  static func validIndices (indices: [Int], _ dimensions: [Int]) -> Bool {
    return indices.count == dimensions.count &&
      zip(indices, dimensions).reduce(true) { $0 && $1.0 > 0 && ($1.0 < $1.1) }
  }

  static func allPositive (values: [Int]) -> Bool {
    return values.map { $0 > 0 }.reduce (true) { $0 && $1 }
  }
}
```